# Post Request in Angular to Node.js is not sending

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, request, rxjs

My goal is simple : I want to **send a post request** from Angular and via http to my node.js

But, the request is not received.

Here is my Angular Code

```
const Data =  [{
'name' : this.userForm.controls.name.value,
'email' : this.userForm.controls.email.value,
'Object': this.userForm.controls.Object.value,
'message': this.userForm.controls.message.value
}];
console.log('ready to send');
this.http.post('http://localhost:8012/sendmail', Data).subscribe();
```

I just **format my data in Data to send it.** It was part of all my try.
The url is good, since I test with get method and it worked !

---

Now in Node.js

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require("path");
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

var db = mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/test", 
function( err, response){
if(err){console.log(err);}
});

var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser());
app.use(bodyParser.json({limit:'10mb'}));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));

app.use(function(req,res,next){
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-
Origin','http://localhost:4200');
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-
Methods','http://localhost:4200','POST');
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow- 
Credentials','http://localhost:4200', true);
next();
});

app.post("/sendmail",function (req, res, next){
console.log("wddddddf");
res.end('buck');
})


app.listen(8012, ()=>{
console.log('waf waf 8012 waf waf');
})
```

Here **I just want to receive data and console.log** to know it's working.

---

My problem is that **the request doesn't seems able to reach my node**.

Does someone could help me to understand why ?

---

Edit :  It still doesn't work with the subscribe. I've this error:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After hours of search, I found the solution :
I add this line in as setHeader:

```
res.setHeader( 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Accept,Accept- 
Language,Content-Language,Content-Type');
```

Comment: What Angular version do you use? You don't have to set headers with HttpClient as opposed to Http service.

Comment: 6.2.2

And effectively, with Postman, the request was working. It's only with angular

Comment: There has to be something else at play too, haven't used 6.0 yet, but since I moved to HttpClient I never had to set headers.

Answer (score 1):

Your request is not being sent because you have not subscribed to `post` request

```
this.http.post('http://localhost:8012/sendmail', Data)
            .subscribe((result) => console.log(result));
```

Comment: Thanks, but it seem it's not the only mistake there is in my code.

Answer (score 1):

You need to subscribe to `post` request:

```
this.http.post('http://localhost:8012/sendmail', Data)
    .subscribe();
```

Angular `Http` and from version 4.3 `HttpClient` use RxJS streams to send (emit using RxJS terminology) data to backend. These streams are lazy evaluated, which means they will not emit any value unless something is subscribed to them.
Hence you need to construct your http calls like this:

```
    this.http.post(url, data)
        .map((response) => {    //optional
           //map over data - do some computation
        })
        .subscribe();
```

Usually the first 4 lines are in the service - wrapped in a function that returns an Observable(), the `.subscribe()` block is in a component calling the service method.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.
However, it seem it was not the only error in my code since it is still not working.

Could the problem come that I import HttpClient from @angular/http and don't importe anything from rxjs ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to import the HttpClient from @angular/common/http, like below.

```
import {HttpClient, HttpHeaders} from '@angular/common/http';
```

See if it works.

Comment: It's already is, I just forgotten I had already set up this route. Thanks anyway !